# Django Forms: Show empty option that evaluates to None

Tags: django, django-forms

When using Django's `ModelChoiceField`, with required=False, an extra choice `('', '--------')` is generated automatically. When selecting this option, it ends up as `None` in the `cleaned_data`. How do I (idiomatically) reproduce this behavior when using a regular `ChoiceField`?

Some things I've noted:

- I have not found any way to automatically add the tuple `('', '---------')` to the list of `choices`, so it appears to be required to add it manually. I feel there should be a way to add it to the choices by setting one of the parameters differently, so if that exists I would love to hear it.
- The conversion from `''` to `None` must still be done manually in the code that uses `cleaned_data`. This means the code that deals with `ModelChoiceField`s has to be subtly different from the `ChoiceField` code, which may possibly lead to subtle bugs. Again: if someone knows better idioms, I'd love to hear that.
- `TypedChoiceField` does some magic handling of `''`. In particular, it does not offer it to the `coerce` function like one would expect.

Consider the following code:

```
def int_or_none(s):
    if s.isnumeric():
        return int(s)
    return None

class NoneForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.TypedChoiceField(
      choices=[('', '--------'), ('1', 'One'), ('2', 'Two')],
      required=False, coerce=int_or_none)

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NoneForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            assert type(form.cleaned_data['field']) in [int, type(None)]
            print form.cleaned_data['field']

    form = NoneForm()
    return HttpResponse(
      """<form method="POST">""" +
      form.as_table() +
      """<input type="submit"></form>""")
```

The assertion above fails!

Can it really be this hard to get Django's various versions of `ChoiceField` to clean to `None` in an idiomatic way?

Comment: You need to provide the `empty_value` parameter. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.TypedChoiceField.empty_value)

Comment: Yes, that's it... I somehow never got empty_value to work, probably because I was working with None rather than the empty string in choices. I'll put a full answer below for clarity's sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result based on [rantanplan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308769/django-forms-show-empty-option-that-evaluates-to-none#comment18212937_13308769) about the `empty_value` parameter.

Note especially that the choice for the empty value is implemented as `''` in the choices (just like in `ModelChoiceField`, so that's good).

```python
class NoneForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.TypedChoiceField(
      choices=[('', '--------'), ('1', 'One'), ('2', 'Two')],
      required=False, coerce=int, empty_value=None)

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NoneForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            assert type(form.cleaned_data['field']) in [int, type(None)]
            print form.cleaned_data['field']

    form = NoneForm()
    return HttpResponse(
      """<form method="POST">""" +
      form.as_table() +
      """<input type="submit"></form>""")
```

Now the assertion succeeds.